# Title of isekai manga/manhwa where isekai is normal but they are level capped

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The only thing I remember from the story is that the main character gets ported to a new world but, before he does he is able to choose a skill. He chooses something like Limit Break or something similar.

In this world it seems to happen often and people who port to the world are usually very weak and cant get much stronger. However, the main character  has chosen Limit Break and is able to level up/get stronger.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the manga/manhwa you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Reincarnated Inferior Magic Swordsman](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/rettoujin-no-maken-tsukai-skill-board-wo-kushishite-saikyou-ni-itaru)*, aka *Rettoujin no Maken Tsukai: Skill Board wo Kushishite Saikyou ni Itaru*

> A normal office worker, Toru Minasuki, was swallowed up by a dimensional fissure and reincarnated into a different world. Upon reincarnation, Toru was given a skill board by God. Make the most of it to acquire all the necessary skills! Even though he is an "inferior person", he'll make his way to the top!

The limit break skill is "break limit";

[image: Break Limit]

The early chapters mention many other people being reincarnated by the goddess, with none of them surviving. This is expanded on in later chapters when he goes to register as an adventurer and is called inferior.

[image: Weak]

Comment: Thanks man, that was exactly the one